# Magento how to move template logo to left column?

Tags: php, magento-1.5, magento

I would like to know how I can change the position of my logo in magento?

By default, the logo are in the header, but I want to move it to left column, I have read that I need to change a block in the XML files, etc., but I don't know what file to change. I don't want to fix it with CSS, I want to use Magento logo function.

Here is the code I want to move to left column template:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" 
class="logo">
<strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" />
</a>
```

Comment: I have tried to move the previous code to 2columns-left.phtml but nothing are show, i'm unable to get the logoSource if i'm in the 2columns-left.phtml but it's work in page/html/header.phtml

Answer (score 1):

In the template `$this` refers to a particular block, so using the same code in another template does not work. The methods `getLogoSrc()` and `getLogoAlt()` are only available in [`Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Page/Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header.html). The solution is to make one of these blocks in the left column but with a custom template.

In an XML layout file add the following:

```
<default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="page/html_header" name="logo">
            <!-- Cannot set "template" param since header block sets it's own in constructor -->
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/logo.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Place your template code in your theme as `template/page/html/logo.phtml`. The left column is a 'text list' so automatically outputs all it's contents, the new block will be rendered for you.